# (IOS 10) RequestAVAssetForVideo result asset = nil

Tags: objective-c, phasset, avurlasset

RequestAVAssetForVideo result nil all the time:

- iOS 10 (**only**) (IOS 11 works great)
- video **not recorded on current iPhone**
- video stored in Photo Library
- Request's localIdentifier = 1BF03030-1CB7-49ED-9314-D0B8D1C34D72/L0/001

> assetUrl = nil

PHAsset* asset = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:@[file.localIdentifier] options:nil].firstObject;

```
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:asset options:nil resultHandler:^(AVAsset *avAsset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {

   //here asset in nil! IOS 10 only, IOS 11 works fine
   AVURLAsset * assetUrl = (AVURLAsset*)avAsset;


}];
```

Comment: Have you fixed this issue? I have come to the same issue on iOS Plus devices with iOS 11